# Computed value based on component's created method

Tags: vuejs2

In my component I have a`created` method where I make a request and then I want to use the data I get for a `computed` property.

```
 computed: {
        ...mapState(["pages"]),
        pageContent() {
            let slug = this.$route.params.slug ? this.$route.params.slug : 'home' ;
            let page = this.pages.find(page => page.slug == slug);
            return page.content;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions(['setPagesAction'])
    },
    created() {
        this.setPagesAction();
    }
```

The problem is that `created` is executed **after** the computed property `pageContent` is read, so it is undefined.

How can I make `pageContent` get the data from `created` ?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

As you know, computed property will update itself when the dependent data changes. ie when `this.pages` is assigned in vuex. So
You have mainly three options.

#### Option 1

Set a variable so that till the time page content is being loaded, a loading spinner etc is being shown.

#### Option 2

If you are using vue-router, then use the beforeRouteEnter guard to load the data.
[like here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-before-navigation)

#### Option 3

Load data initially (when app starts) and add it to vuex. (you can use vuex modules for seperating data store if needed)